How to use the git service connection in an Azure Devops pipeline to access the Github API
I have a github service connection that has permissions for my enterprise git server. My script however other than cloning repos does some analysis on github more gitrepos by using the github API.
I wanted to use the service connection to authenticate to the API instead of defining a new token(which works) so I can use this to get repos from the API for example I am fetching all repos beginning with a give prefix and reporting back some statistics

You can install the third-party extension Github AzureDevOps Rest Api Integration in your organization and then use the GitHub service connection for authentication.
For example, call GitHub API to create a PR:
- task: azuredevopsgithub@0
  inputs:
    gitHubConnection: '{The GitHub service connection you created}'
    method: 'POST'
    body: |
      {
        "title": "Merging changes from branch1 to main",
        "head": "refs/heads/branch1",
        "base": "refs/heads/main",
        "body": "Test creating PR in Azure pipeline"
      }
    githubrestapiurl: 'https://api.github.com/repos/{GitHubOwner}/{Repo}/pulls'

